# Image() onLoad not waiting for image to load

Tags: javascript, image, slideshow

I've figured out the centering and resizing issues, but I still can't get `onLoad` to work properly. Anyone have any ideas? I thought `onLoad` was supposed to wait for the image to be loaded completely before firing the code. As this is right now, it resizes the img for the next img, and fades it in before it's loaded, so the previous image fades in again. Once the show has run through once, it works perfectly, so obviously it's not waiting for the image to load completely before firing `imageLoad()`.

```
<div id="slideShow">
    <div id="slideShowImg" style="display:none; margin-right:auto; margin-left:auto;">
    </div>
    <div id="slideShowThumbs">
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        loadXMLDoc('http://www.thehoppr.com/hopspots/82/82.xml', function() {
            var slideShow = document.getElementById('slideShow');
            var items = [];
            var nl = xmlhttp.responseXML.getElementsByTagName('image');
            var i = 0;
            var t;
            var slideShowImg = document.getElementById('slideShowImg');
            var slideShow = document.getElementById('slideShow');
            var maxHeight = 300;
            var maxWidth = 800;
            var imgNode = new Image();


            function image() {
                var nli = nl.item(i);
                var src = nli.getAttribute('src').toString();
                var width = parseInt(nli.getAttribute('width').toString());
                var height = parseInt(nli.getAttribute('height').toString());
                imgNode.onLoad = imageLoad();
                imgNode.src = src;
                imgNode.height = height;
                imgNode.width = width;
                imgNode.setAttribute("style", "margin-right:auto; margin-left:auto; display:block;");

                var ratio = maxHeight / maxWidth;
                if (imgNode.height / imgNode.width > ratio) {
                    // height is the problem
                    if (imgNode.height > maxHeight) {
                        imgNode.width = Math.round(imgNode.width * (maxHeight / imgNode.height));
                        imgNode.height = maxHeight;
                    }
                } else {
                    // width is the problem
                    if (imgNode.width > maxHeight) {
                        imgNode.height = Math.round(imgNode.height * (maxWidth / imgNode.width));
                        imgNode.width = maxWidth;
                    }
                }
            }

            function imageLoad() {
                slideShowImg.appendChild(imgNode);
                Effect.Appear('slideShowImg', {
                    duration: 1
                });

                t = setTimeout(nextImage, 7000);
            }

            function nextImage() {
                slideShowImg.setAttribute("style", "display:none");
                if (i < nl.length - 1) {
                    i++;
                    image();
                } else {
                    i = 0;
                    image();
                }
            }

            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                //XML Loaded, create the slideshow
                alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
                image();
            }
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Interesting enough it appears to actually work in Chrome, but not IE or Firefox. Obviously the script is pulling from the cache before the onLoad even gets assigned? Preloading an image while the other is being shown is probably going to be my best bet here. If anyone can provide me with some sample code that might speed this up would be appreciated, I'm fairly new to Javascript. It's late though and I'm heading to bed.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some of my thoughts (it's all open discussion)...

1. Preloading - Since you're limited to downloading 2 resources in parallel *per hostname*, it may not make sense to preload everything up front.  Since it's a slideshow, how about modifying image() to download the i + 1 image through an Image object that doesn't get appended to the DOM?  It doesn't seem beneficial to prefetch i + 2 and beyond in a slideshow setting.
2. Centering the images - Regarding using the auto margin width for horizontal centering, I believe you'll have to explicitly set the image to display:block.  Obviously that doesn't solve centering vertically.  Are all the images the same size?  Also, will the slideShowImg div have a defined height/width?  If so, then some math can be applied to achieve the centering.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: I was able to figure out the centering and resizing. I'm using the onLoad event now to trigger the animation effect that makes the div container appear, but that does not appear to work no matter what sort of configuration I try. i thought the onLoad event was supposed to wait for the image to be loaded and then it fires the code you want. Preloading one image ahead sounds like a good idea as well, could you include some sample code?See my updated code above!

Answer (score 1):

Ok so I fixed the issue with the onLoad, and I even added a little preloading to help the slideshow along as well. All I had to do was define the onload first, and then do everything else except define the src inside the onload's function. I then added a little nextImg preloading so there's little if no hiccup between images even if it's the first time the browser is loading them. **Here's the final code for anyone who has similar onload issues and finds there way here:**

```
<div id="slideShow">
    <div id="slideShowImg" style="display:none; margin-right:auto; margin-left:auto;">
    </div>
    <div id="slideShowThumbs">
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        loadXMLDoc('/82.xml', function() {
            var slideShow = document.getElementById('slideShow');
            var items = [];
            var nl = xmlhttp.responseXML.getElementsByTagName('image');
            var i = 0;
            var t;
            var slideShowImg = document.getElementById('slideShowImg');
            var slideShow = document.getElementById('slideShow');
            var maxHeight = 300;
            var maxWidth = 800;
            var curImg = new Image();
            var nextImg = new Image();

            function image() {
                var cli = nl.item(i);
                var src = cli.getAttribute('src').toString();
                var width = parseInt(cli.getAttribute('width').toString());
                var height = parseInt(cli.getAttribute('height').toString());
                curImg.onload = function() {
                    curImg.height = height;
                    curImg.width = width;
                    curImg.setAttribute("style", "margin-right:auto; margin-left:auto; display:block;");
                    slideShowImg.appendChild(curImg);
                    var ratio = maxHeight / maxWidth;
                    if (curImg.height / curImg.width > ratio) {
                        // height is the problem
                        if (curImg.height > maxHeight) {
                            curImg.width = Math.round(curImg.width * (maxHeight / curImg.height));
                            curImg.height = maxHeight;
                        }
                    } else {
                        // width is the problem
                        if (curImg.width > maxHeight) {
                            curImg.height = Math.round(curImg.height * (maxWidth / curImg.width));
                            curImg.width = maxWidth;
                        }
                    }
                }
                curImg.src = src;
                if (i < nl.length - 1) {
                    var nli = nl.item(i + 1);
                    var nsrc = nli.getAttribute('src').toString();
                    nextImg.src = nsrc;
                }
                Effect.Appear('slideShowImg', {
                    duration: 1
                });

                t = setTimeout(nextImage, 7000);
            }

            function imageLoad() {}

            function nextImage() {
                slideShowImg.removeChild(curImg);
                slideShowImg.setAttribute("style", "display:none");
                if (i < nl.length - 1) {
                    i++;
                    image();
                } else {
                    i = 0;
                    image();
                }
            }

            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                //XML Loaded, create the slideshow
                alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
                image();
            }
        });
    </script>
```